# Wordpress plugin options need to delete after deactivate & uninstall

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a WordPress plugin and I need to delete the options I am creating when uninstalling. What I did is I created a file called uninstall.php and included the following code:

```
<?php

function WCM_Setup_Demo_on_uninstall()
{
  //if uninstall not called from WordPress exit
  if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN'))
    exit();

  $video - thumbnail1 = 'video-thumbnail1';


  // For Single site
  if (!is_multisite()) {
    delete_option($video - thumbnail1);
  }
}

?>
```

And included this in my main plugin file:

```
register_uninstall_hook('uninstall.php', 'WCM_Setup_Demo_on_uninstall');
```

This is how i'm registering the option in my main plugin file:

```
register_setting( 'baw-settings-group', 'video-thumbnail1' );
```

When I deactivated and deleted the plugin from the dashboard, the plugin gets deactivated but not deleted. When one press delete a blank white page comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With activate/deactivate hooks:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_uninstall_hook
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook

I **don't** post a example, you found it on the WordPress-Codex.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, I have updated my question if you can provide me some help please

Comment: `When one press delete a blank white page comes up.` - Set-up the error-reporting **or look** into your error-log file!

Comment: **Rename** `$video-thumbnail1` to `$video_thumbnail1`, a `-` in a variable name will **not work**

Comment: using `register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__,... ` how will I call the uninstall.php file ?

Comment: I will create you an simple example as `ZIP Archive`, wait a little bit.

Comment: I implemented your solution but for some reason when I deleted the plugin the option from wp_options table didn't delete - Obviously amended the code with my options name

Comment: Are you **delete** the complete plugin or you only **deactivate** that? Otherwise use the `register_deactivation_hook` if you need to delete the options after a **deactivation**

Comment: I am doing both and I want the options table to clear the respective row once the user clicks the delete button.

Comment: Check out if you have errors (see the erro log or set-up your error reporting). Normally, these will be work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54145/discussion-between-user3492795-and-adrian-preuss).